# Principal Component Analysis not working

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to do principal component analysis on datasets containing images, but whenever I want to apply pca.transform from the sklearn.decomposition module I keep getting this error: ***AttributeError: 'PCA' object has no attribute 'mean_'***. I know what this error means, but I have no clue how to fix it. I reckon some of you guys know how to fix this.

Thank you for your help

My code:

```
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

image_dir1 = "C:\Users\private\Desktop\K FOLDER\private\train"
image_dir2 = "C:\Users\private\Desktop\K FOLDER\private\test1"
Standard_size = (300,200)
pca = PCA(n_components = 10)
file_open = lambda x,y: glob.glob(os.path.join(x,y))


def matrix_image(image_path):
    "opens image and converts it to a m*n matrix" 
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    print("changing size from %s to %s" % (str(image.size), str(Standard_size)))
    image = image.resize(Standard_size)
    image = list(image.getdata())
    image = map(list,image)
    image = np.array(image)
    return image
def flatten_image(image):  
    """
    takes in a n*m numpy array and flattens it to 
    an array of the size (1,m*n)
    """
    s = image.shape[0] * image.shape[1]
    image_wide = image.reshape(1,s)
    return image_wide[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    train_images = file_open(image_dir1,"*.jpg")
    test_images = file_open(image_dir2,"*.jpg")
    train_set = []
    test_set = []

    "Loop over all images in files and modify them"
    train_set = [flatten_image(matrix_image(image)) for image in train_images]
    test_set = [flatten_image(matrix_image(image)) for image in test_images]
    train_set = np.array(train_set)
    test_set = np.array(test_set)
    train_set = pca.fit_transform(train_set) "line where error occurs"
    test_set = pca.fit_transform(test_set)
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Private\workspace\final_submission\src\d.py", line 54, in <module>
    train_set = pca.transform(train_set)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\pca.py", line 298, in transform
    if self.mean_ is not None:
AttributeError: 'PCA' object has no attribute 'mean_'
```

**Edit1:** 
So I tried to fit the model before transforming it, and now I'm getting an even weirder error. I looked it up, and it involves f2py, a module that ports Fortran to Python which is part of the Numpy Library.

```
File "C:\Users\Private\workspace\final_submission\src\d.py", line 54, in <module>
    pca.fit(train_set)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\pca.py", line 200, in fit
    self._fit(X)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\pca.py", line 249, in _fit
    U, S, V = linalg.svd(X, full_matrices=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\decomp_svd.py", line 100, in svd
    full_matrices=full_matrices, overwrite_a = overwrite_a)
ValueError: failed to create intent(cache|hide)|optional array-- must have defined dimensions but got (0,)
```

**Edit2:**

So I have checked if my train_set and data_set contained any data and they don't. 
I've checked my image_dirs, and they contain the right locations(just for clarity, I got them by going to the actual files, looking at the properties of one the images and copied the location). The fault should lie somewhere else.

Comment: You should provide full traceback.

Comment: True. I will, give me a second.

Comment: maybe you should `fit()` first ?

Comment: It looks like your `train_set` is empty. Can you verify that it really contains expected data?

Comment: That could indeed be the problem. I'll check if my image_dir is right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should fit the model before transform:

```
train_set = np.array(train_set)
test_set = np.array(test_set)

pca.fit(train_set)
pca.fit(test_set)

train_set = pca.transform(train_set) "line where error occurs"
test_set = pca.transform(test_set)
```

**Edit**

Second error indicate that your `train_set` is empty. It can be easily reproduced using this code:

```
train_set = np.array([[]])
pca.fit(train_set)
```

I think one problem is in `flatten_image` function. I may be wrong but this line will raise `AttributeError`

```
image.wide = image.reshape(1,s)
```

It can be replaced with:

```
image_wide = image.reshape(1,s)
return image_wide[0]
```

This line is problematic too:

```
print("changing size from %s to %s" % str(image.size), str(Standard_size))
```

Read http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations for more details, but `values must be a tuple`. So you want this instead:

```
print("changing size from %s to %s" % (str(image.size), str(Standard_size)))
```

**Another edit**

At last you replace loops aftert `"Loop over all images in files and modify them"` with:

```
train_set = [flatten_image(matrix_image(image)) for image in train_images]
test_set = [flatten_image(matrix_image(image)) for image in test_images]
```

Right now you call `file_open` so it will look for files in path like this: `"C:\Users\private\Desktop\K FOLDER\private\train\C:\Users\private\Desktop\K FOLDER\private\train\foo.jpg"` and you get empty list instead of file name.

Comment: I tried this before with pca.transform and got an even weirder error. I looked it up on the internet, and it involved f2py a library that ports Fortran code to Python. I'll do an edit for more info.

Comment: This one isn't weird. `mean_` field is set when you call `PCA.fit` so there it can be set before. You can always use `fit_transform` like @jabaldonedo proposed below.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. However, I'm still getting the error, so it lies somewhere else. I was thinking about my lambda function, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Check the last edit. Right now you call `file_open` twice. First when you create `train_images`, second time in for loop. It will give you empty list.

Comment: I see, but I'm a bit puzzled now. What should I delete?

Comment: Yes, the same one in eddit1.

Comment: Like I said before - everything looks more or less OK. I checked it a moment ago and runs as it should without errors. Check if `train_images` and `test_images` contain expected list of files.

Comment: Checked again. They are still empty lists. So my open_file isn't working correctly. I haven't used the glob and os module before, so I'll have to look in that more thoroughly. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to apply `fit_transform` instead of `transform`. You need to generate the model using either `fit` or `fit_transform`.

This is what documentation says about each method:

> fit(X, y=None) 
>   Fit the model with X.
>
> fit_transform(X, y=None)
>   Fit the model with X and apply the dimensionality reduction on X.

You are applying `transform` directly so no model has already been generated.

Comment: Seems a problem with your dataset, have you checked that X and y data have same number of samples and they are not empty?